Kolmogorov continuity theorem and boundness of the modification
Consider the Kolmogorov continuity theorem: Let $(X_r)_{r \in \mathbb{R}_+}$ be a stochastic processes taking values in a separable complete normed vector space $(E,\Vert \cdot \Vert)$ such that $$\exists (\alpha,\beta,c) \in \mathbb{R}_+^*\times ]1,+\infty[\times \mathbb{R}_+,\forall (r,u) \in (\mathbb{R}_+)^2,E[\Vert X_r-X_u\Vert^\alpha] \leq c|u-r|^\beta,$$ then there exists a continuous modification $(\widetilde{X}_r)_{r \in \mathbb{R}_+}$ of $(X_r)_{r \in \mathbb{R}_+}$ taking values in $E.$ Also the paths of the modification are $\gamma$-Holder for $0<\gamma<\frac{\beta-1}{\alpha}.$
While I was reading a book, they used that for every $U \in \mathbb{R}_+,E[\sup_{r \in [0,U]}\Vert \widetilde{X}_r\Vert]\leq c.$ But why is this true? Can we claim that for every $U \in \mathbb{R}_+,\sup_{r \in [0,U]}\Vert \widetilde{X}_r\Vert\leq c?$ (without expectation)

For your second question, you can not say that $\sup_{r\in[0,U]}|\tilde{X}_r|\leq c$ for every $U\in[0,\infty)$. Take for example the Brownian motion $W$ on $(\mathbb{R},d)$, then for each $t<0$, the support of the probability measure $P_t$ is $\mathbb{R}$, hence there always is a small probability that $|W_t|\geq c$ for every $c\geq 0$.
